# Read a trash file from C++

Tags: c++, linux, file-handling, recycle-bin

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int count, char* argv[])
{
  if(count!=2)
  {
    // print_syntax(argv[0]);
  }
  else if(count==2)
  {
    string file_name=argv[1];
    // cout<<file_name<<endl;
    string file_directory="~/.local/share/Trash/info/"+file_name+".trashinfo";
    cout<<file_directory<<endl;
    ifstream myReadFile;
     myReadFile.open(file_directory);
     char output[100];
     if (myReadFile.is_open()) 
     {
        cout<<"here";
     while (!myReadFile.eof()) 
     {


        myReadFile >> output;
        cout<<output;


     }
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Not working";
    }
    myReadFile.close();
}
}
```

I am trying to read a file from trash which further has two subfolders, the info one containing meta data for deleted file with an extension of .trashinfo

But due to some reason, I am not able to open that file in this program.

```
root@kali:~/projects/Linux-Commands/Restore# ./a.out hero
~/.local/share/Trash/info/hero.trashinfo
Not working
root@kali:~/projects/Linux-Commands/Restore# vi ~/.local/share/Trash/info/hero.trashinfo
```

By using this vi command, I can easily open it in the terminal and even edit it.

Comment: '~' is expanded by shell and does not work if you do it from a C++ program. Please check have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910377/get-home-directory-in-linux-c

Comment: ~ can't be used to refer to user's private diretory in that context.

Comment: True that I learned something new today. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `~` to refer to the user's home directory in a C++ program - this character is expanded by the **shell**, not the OS in general.

You should either specify an absolute path, or use `getenv` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570698/accessing-linux-user-home-directory-with-fstream).

An easier fix is just to pass the full path to the file to your program, and not worry about modifying it inside your program (`file_directory = argv[1]`, rather than your current). Then, from the shell, you can type

```
a.out "~/.local/share/Trash/info/hero.trashinfo"
```

and the shell will expand `~` as you expect. The quotation marks are to ensure that if you have spaces in your path, the full path is passed in as a single string rather than being split up by the shell into multiple arguments.

Comment: Any help to access that file?

Comment: a.out ~/.local/share/Trash/info/hero.trashinfo

that's the trick I am willing to use, the user will just input the file name and it'll provide the time it was deleted